# Makefile recreates missing dependency files only when a static pattern rule is used

Tags: design-patterns, makefile, static, gnu, rules

Consider the makefile code in Listing 1.  The goal is to generate a dependency file $(DEPDIR)/%.d for each object file %.o generated when the C compiler is invoked on line 9.  Specifically, the dependency files are generated as a side-effect of invoking the C compiler on line 9 to translate a %.c file into a %.o file--i.e., line 9 emits two files: $(DEPDIR)/%.d and %.o.

*Listing 1.*

```
1   DEPDIR := deps
2
3   SOURCES.c  := $(wildcard *.c)
4   OBJS.c  := $(SOURCES.c:.c=.o)
5
6   CPP_DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d
#
#   Other rules, variable definitions, etc. are here...
#
7   %.o : %.c
8   $(OBJS.c) : %.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
9       $(COMPILE.c) $(CPP_DEPFLAGS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
10
11  $(DEPDIR) : ; mkdir -p $@
12
13  # Ensure make considers missing $(DEPDIR)/%.d files as "not updated"
14  $(DEPDIR)/%.d : ;
15
16  # [EDIT]
17  .PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

This makefile code works as desired<strike>, but I don't understand why (see below)</strike>. Specifically, invoking make creates the DEPDIR folder if it does not exist, and the recipe on line 9 emits the $(DEPDIR)/%.d files as well as the %.o files.

Now assume the user deletes one or more of the %.d files, or the entire DEPDIR folder.  Reinvoking make rebuilds the missing dependency files as desired<strike>, but again, I don't understand why</strike>.

```
$ rm -fr depdir *.o
$ make # Generates DEPDIR and the $(DEPDIR)/%.d files
$ rm -fr depdir
# NB: The %.o files still exist
$ make # Regenerates DEPDIR and the $(DEPDIR)/%.d files
```

Now replace the static pattern rule on line 8 with the implicit rule shown in Listing 2, and otherwise leave everything else as it was:

*Listing 2.*

```
7   %.o : %.c
8   %.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
9       $(COMPILE.c) $(CPP_DEPFLAGS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

When an implicit rule is used, make does not regenerate deleted/missing dependency files--which is **NOT** the outcome I expected:

```
$ rm -fr depdir *.o
$ make # Generates DEPDIR and the $(DEPDIR)/%.d files
$ rm -fr depdir
# NB: The %.o files still exist
$ make # Generates DEPDIR only; DOES NOT regenerate the $(DEPDIR)/%.d files
```

The static pattern rule version considers the deleted/missing prerequisite $(DEPDIR)/%.d (on line 8) to be **updated** <strike>(which I did NOT expect)</strike> by the rule on line 14, thus making the %.o target out-of-date, and therefore the recipe on line 9 is invoked to rebuild the %.o file.

The implicit pattern rule, on the other hand, apparently considers the deleted/missing prerequisite $(DEPDIR)/%.d (on line 8) to be <strike>**not updated**</strike> up-to-date (which is **NOT** what I expected), and therefore make considers the %.o target up-to-date and the recipe on line 9 is not invoked.

So why does the implicit pattern rule (Listing 2) not invoke the recipe line on line 9?  I don't find anything in the GNU Make documentation to explain this difference between a static pattern rule and an implicit rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand this you might consider reading [Auto-dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).  But to explain:

The reason the static pattern rule works is because of line 14:

```
13  # Ensure make considers missing $(DEPDIR)/%.d files as "not updated"
14  $(DEPDIR)/%.d : ;
```

This creates an implicit rule that says how to build a `.d` file giving an empty recipe.  The recipe doesn't do anything but if make needs to run it make will consider any target depending on it out of date.  Thus, if the file is missing make will rebuild any target that depends on it.

*Removed original incorrect answer*

OK now I tried it myself and figured it out.

The reason your implicit rule doesn't work is that the `.d` files are considered [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html).  Because they're intermediate files, if they don't exist then make doesn't try to rebuild them unless they need to be rebuilt for some other reason; here there isn't one.

You can show that my theory is correct by first deleting all the `.d` files then touching the `.c` files to force them to be rebuilt:

```
$ touch *.c
$ rm deps/*.d
$ make
cc    -c -MT a.o -MMD -MF deps/a.d -o a.o a.c
cc    -c -MT b.o -MMD -MF deps/b.d -o b.o b.c
cc    -c -MT d.o -MMD -MF deps/d.d -o d.o d.c
rm deps/a.d deps/d.d deps/b.d
```

Note the last line here: that's make removing all intermediate files.

If you check my blog post above you'll see that I recommended changing the implicit rule to an explicit rule, for you that would be something like this:

```
$(SOURCES.c:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d):
```

Now all the `.d` files are explicit targets, and thus cannot be intermediate.

Note the blog post I link above gives a slightly better way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW, my makefile code sample does cancel the make's built-in rule '%.o:%.c" (see line 7). Line 7 remains "as is" after changing the static pattern rule on line 8 to an implicit rule.

Comment: Thanks again for spending additional time testing this.  In my real makefile I declare the dependency files $(DEPDIR)/%.d as .PRECIOUS to ensure make doesn't automatically delete them.  I apologize for leaving out that detail in my sample above. I'll add that line to the code sample in my original post; that's an important detail.

Comment: That is not sufficient.  Declaring something as `.PRECIOUS` doesn't make it non-intermediate, it just means it won't be deleted automatically.  However it's still considered intermediate, in that it won't be recreated if it doesn't exist (as you experienced).  Also you really _don't_ want these files to be precious: if they are then they'll be preserved even with ^C etc. and they could be corrupted and break your build.  The right way to handle this is to simply declare the `.d` files as targets, somewhere in the makefile: then they cannot be intermediate which is what you want.

Comment: If you have your answer please mark the question as resolved by clicking the check mark next to the answer to the question, so it doesn't appear as an open question in the list; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation the problem with Listing 1 in my original post is line #14:

```
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
```

Yikes. What was I thinking!? This line should instead be expressed via a substitution reference (or via a call to patsubst, etc.):

```
$(OBJS:%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.d): ;
```

Or to follow MadScientist's suggestion which, IMHO, offers improved readability (and with a slight variation on my part to use OBJS instead of SOURCES),

```
DEPFILES := $(OBJS:%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
$(DEPFILES): ;
```

where

```
OBJS.c := $(SOURCES.c:%.c=%.o)
OBJS.cc := $(SOURCES.cc:%.cc=%.o)
OBJS := $(OBJS.c) $(OBJS.cc)
```

After changing/fixing line #14 my makefile consistently invokes recipe line #9 (in Listing 1) to rebuild deleted/missing dependency files for both the static pattern rule case and the implicit rule case.

[EDIT]

Per MadScientist's comments I've removed the .PRECIOUS line from the makefile as it is no longer needed (after making the changes I've described above) and the .PRECIOUS line could cause unwanted behavior.

Comment: `the .PRECIOUS line could cause unwanted behavior` In fact, I never could understand why people keep using `.PRECIOUS` here and there while in 99% cases they mean `.SECONDARY` (just to keep intermediates intact, but never to pollute the file system on interrupt). However, as it was already mentioned, for this particular case implicit chains of rules should not be used at all.